# expected distance

Tags: statistics

Let P be a point chosen at random from the unit disk.  The unit disk is the disk of radius 1 centered at the origin.  It is described by the condition $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$.
"At random" means "according to a uniform distribution."  Find the expected distance of P from the origin.

Is there a formula for expected distance of a point? I think I can solve it if there is a formula, otherwise how do I get this problem started? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $D$ be our disk. The joint density function is $\frac{1}{\pi}$ in the interior of the disk, and $0$ elsewhere. Then the distance of the point $(x,y)$ from the origin is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. So if $W$ is the distance of a randomly chosen point from the origin, then 
$$E(W)=\iint_D \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot \frac{1}{\pi} \,dx\,dy.$$
For the actual integration, switch to polar coordinates. We get
$$E(W)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\int_0^1 r\cdot r\,dr\right) \,d\theta.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint:  given a point $P$ chosen uniformly at random from the disk $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 \le 1\}$, what is the probability distribution for the distance $d(P) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ from the origin?

Think of it this way:  consider the set of all points $P$ in $D$ such that the distance $d(P) \in [r, r + dr)$ for some "small" differential width $dr$.  This is a "ring" with inner radius $r$ and outer radius $r + dr$.  What is the area of such a region?  What is the probability that a randomly chosen point in $D$ falls in this region?  What is the limit of this probability divided by the width $dr$ as $dr \to 0$?  This gives you the resulting probability density as a function of $r$.